# Use of home plug in a snapcraft.yaml file

Tags: snap

If my program want's to write into /home/user/.local/myapp/somefile, do I have to put home plug in a snapcraft.yaml file or will it write there anyway?

It's not a classic snap, so will the user have to connect after installing the snap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home plug won't allow access to dotfiles/directories in the host home directory. However it will be able to access the confined home directory - typically `/home/$USER/snap/$SNAP/current`.

Comment: is the plug auto-connected in a 'normal' snap?

Comment: The home plug is automatically connected. Although as popey mentioned, you don't need the home plug if you just need to write to $HOME/.hidden-location, but $HOME will actually be pointing to `/home/<user>/snap/<snapname>/current`.

Comment: When I tried this I now get an error when running:  no GSettings shemas are installed, also, it tries to write default home/user/subdirectories (but isn't allowed).